# How to wait for some period of time and after that just return default value?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout

I have below code which tells me whether my data is PARTIAL or FULL. It works fine most of the time.

```
public static String getTypeOfData {
    DataType type = new SelectTypes().getType();
    if (type == DataType.partial || type == DataType.temp) {
        return "partial";
    }
    return "full";
}
```

But sometimes, this line `DataType type = new SelectTypes().getType();` just hangs and it keeps on waiting forever. This code is not in my control as it is developed by some other teams.

What I want to do is if this line `DataType type = new SelectTypes().getType();` takes more than 10 second (or any default number of second), my method should return back a default string which can be `partial`.

Is this  possible to do by any chance? Any example will help me to understand better.

I am using Java 7.

Comment: That would depend if the API your calling supports `Thread#interrupt`

Comment: You could enclose that instruction in a Runnable and run it in a separate Thread.

Comment: It doesn't support `Thread#interrupt` so I cannot use this option.

Answer (score 3):

The [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) provides methods which allow you to schedule tasks and invoke them with timeout options. This should do what you are after, however, please pay attention since terminating threads could leave your application **in an inconsistent state.**

If possible, you should contact the owners of the API and ask for clarification or more information.

EDIT: As per your comment, would caching be a possibility? Meaning that on start up, or some other point, you application goes through the `SelectTypes` and gets their type and stores them. Assuming that these do not change often, you can save them/update them periodically.

EDIT 2: As per your other comment, I cannot really add much more detail. You would need to add a method call which would allow your application to set these up the moment it is launched (this will depend on what framework you are using, if any).

A possible way would be to make the class containing the `getTypeOfData()` method as a `Singleton`. You would then amend the class to pull this information as part of its creation mechanism. Lastly, you would then create a `Map<String, Type>` in which you would throw in all your types. You could use `getClass().getName()` to populate the key for your map, and what you are doing now for the value part.

Comment: Yes it has to be only startup and get cached so it's one time initialization for me. If possible, can you provide an example how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not well aware of executor service then the easiest way to achieve this is by using Thread wait and notify mechanism:

```
private final static Object lock = new Object();
private static DataType type = null;
public static String getTypeOfData {
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fetchData();
                }
            }).start();

  synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    lock.wait(10000);//ensures that thread doesn't wait for more than 10 sec
                    if (type == DataType.partial || type == DataType.temp) {
                        return "partial";
                    }else{
                        return "full";
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    return "full";
}

private static void fetchData() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            type = new SelectTypes().getType();
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
```

You might have to do some little changes to make it work and looks better like instead of creating new thread directly you can use a Job to do that and some other changes based on your requirement. But the main idea remains same that Thread would only wait for max 10 sec to get the response.